# How can I get a tickerid in pine script for a virtual security

Tags: pine-script

I'd like to get a tickerid for a virtual security so that I can process it for other operations.  An example would be looking at the ratio of "(APPL + MSFT) / GOOGL".  Once I have this, then I can chart it and/or pass it on to RSI and Stochastic and analyze it further (highest, days since, etc).

Clearly it is possible to do this tradingview because I can enter it in the interactive chart and everything works fine.  But I'd like to parameterize this and pass it on to a script. I know that I could get each security individually and then add them up and get their ratios and create a variable for OHLC and then...

But that is messy and inflexible.  So I am really after a way to get a source for a virtual security.

In case someone wants to know, the end goal is to develop a strategy for pair trades that could be made as long/short relative to some ETF (for hedging).

I've tried variations of the code below (with/without quotes and simplifying to only two stock additions).  It compiles without error but produces no results.

thanks for your help

```
t1 = ticker.new("NASDAQ", "APPL", session.regular)
t2 = ticker.new("NASDAQ", "MSFT", session.regular)
t3 = ticker.new("NASDAQ", "GOOG", session.regular)
c = request.security( "t1+t2/t3", "1D", close)
plot(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

spread ticker can be requested like this:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

spread = "NASDAQ:AAPL + NASDAQ:MSFT / NASDAQ:GOOG"

regularSessionTicker = ticker.modify(spread, session.regular)

c = request.security(regularSessionTicker, "1D", close)

plot(c)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This worked for the parts that I needed, but now I have a related problem.  How do I make one of the tickers be the current ticker rather than hard coding it as in above?

Comment: you can use input variable, like `spread = input.text_area("NASDAQ:AAPL + NASDAQ:MSFT / NASDAQ:GOOG")` and then write desired one in the input settings window

Comment: Thanks again. I have one last question on this subject. I am trying to build a PNF signal based on an adjusted version of the price. Example the price to sales ratio.  Something like:
 
.

salespershare = get the revenue from last quarter // I will look this up
ps = ticker.modify(syminfo.tickerid/salespershare, session.regular)
pnfTicker = ticker.pointfigure(ps, "hl", "ATR", 14, 3)
pnfC = request.security(pnfTicker, timeframe.period, close], barmerge.gaps_off)
 
.

There just doesn't seem to be a way to modify the current ticker by an amount
plot(pnfC, color.rgb(176, 134, 79))